# Global validation using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Please Suggest me About any link for validation. I am going to create new application. it had more than 100 pages. Each page must include the field validation.This action will increase my time and also increase the coding. so i need a file that include all type of validation i just call that file where i need the validation for this i wrote validation code manually but it does not working due to the syntax error because the validation file has 50 fields name but the calling file had only 5 field so it shows syntax error. Is there any way to add global validation. THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you have tried.

Comment: Even if you add global validation, you'll still need to modify the existing pages to add the required rules. This is a good library : http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://validval.frebsite.nl/) can help you.